# Resize2fs keeps asking me to run e2fsck -f

Tags: partition, lvm, resize2fs, e2fsck

I set-up a server with LVM, and I just recently extended one of my logical volumes from 25TB to 35.

```
root@server:/home/user# df -h /dev/mapper/vg--data-lv--data
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg--data-lv--data     25T  9.3T   15T  40% /DATA

root@server:/home/user# lvs /dev/mapper/vg--data-lv--data
  LV      VG      Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv-data vg-data -wi-ao---- 34.90t
```

In order to apply the change to the filesystem, I ran e2fsck and then resize2fs, but resize2fs keeps asking me to run e2fsck first :

```
root@server:/home/user# resize2fs /dev/vg-data/lv-data
resize2fs 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/vg-data/lv-data' first.

root@server:/home/user# e2fsck -f /dev/vg-data/lv-data
e2fsck 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/vg-data/lv-data: 672943/836247552 files (3.1% non-contiguous), 2546845858/6689948672 blocks
root@server:/home/user# resize2fs /dev/vg-data/lv-data
resize2fs 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/vg-data/lv-data' first
```

I've been looking all over the web, but I still can't get what the problem is about.
I found [someone having a similar issue](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1038056&p=6542014#post6542014), and it was because e2fsck and resize2fs were running on different versions. This is not my case as you can see above (e2fsprogs is version 1.43.5).

I also found [this very old Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/373409) refering to a time issue.
I checked, and I indeed had a network issue which resulted in a wrong time on my system. I fixed it, and I even checked the hwclock was synced with the systems date. But it still doesn't work, and I still can't resize my filesystem.

I absolutely don't get this, since there's not even a single error/warning message (and since it worked one day before when doing the exact same operation on a smaller lvm partition).

Maybe someone has an idea ??

**EDIT :**

Problem solved thanks to [wurtel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446934/resize2fs-keeps-asking-me-to-run-e2fsck-f?noredirect=1#comment810823_446934) !
Easy solution : don't unmount the partition and do an online resizing... The solution is so easy and seems so obvious... I feel really stupid...
Thank you very much

```
root@server:/home/user# mount -a
root@server:/home/user# df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg--data-lv--data     25T  9.3T   15T  40% /DATA

root@server:/home/user# resize2fs /dev/vg-data/lv-data
resize2fs 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
Filesystem at /dev/vg-data/lv-data is mounted on /DATA; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 3191, new_desc_blocks = 4467
The filesystem on /dev/vg-data/lv-data is now 9367890944 (4k) blocks long.

root@server:/home/user# df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg--data-lv--data     35T  9.3T   24T  29% /DATA
```

Comment: Have you downgraded ext3 to ext2? Have you umounted it?

Comment: Try mounting the filesystem first, as then the resize utility will assume that the filesystem is OK (otherwise it couldn't have been mounted) and will do an online resize.

Comment: @user60561 I closed this question because the OP got their answer in a comment, and thus no longer have a problem that needs to be solved. It's unfortunate that no one posted an actual answer (neither wurtel nor the OP).

Comment: For me it was about the hardware time not synchronized with the system time. I fixed with ` hwclock --systohc`.

Comment: @wurtel bravo, solved the problem exactly as you suggested

Comment: @JacopoDT Thank you, correcting my timezone settings works for me.

Comment: Running `resize2fs` with the `-f` argument should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Broken fix in 1.44.4 (for ext4)

```
root@server:~# resize2fs -p '/dev/sdc5' 414144512K
resize2fs 1.44.4 (18-Aug-2018)
Filesystem at /dev/sdc5 is mounted on /mnt; on-line resizing required
resize2fs: On-line shrinking not supported
```

use first:

```
root@server:~# fsck /dev/sdc5
```